# Singletone PDO используя namespace

Tags: pdo, namespace, singleton

Пытаюсь сделать singletone PDO с namespace. Вот класс Db подключения

```
namespace liw\components;

    class Db {

        private static $_db = null;

        private function __construct() {}
        private function __clone() {}
        private function __wakeup() {}

        public static function getInstance() {
            if (self::$_db === null) {        
                $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=table";
                self::$_db = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '');
            }
            return self::$_db;
        }
  }
```

Попытки обращения к классу Db в модели приводят к ошибке

> Class 'liw\components\PDO' not found

```
    namespace liw\models;

    class Test {

      private $_db = null;

      public function __construct() {
          $this->_db = \liw\components\Db::getInstance();
      }

      public function getList() {       

        $list= array();

        $result = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM table");

        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $list[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];            
            $i++;
        }

        return $list;
    }

  }
```

Я так понимаю, что идет попытка создать класс PDO, у которого нет namespace. Как это исправить?

Comment: а загрузка классов например через `spl_autoload_register` производилась? В PHP нет автоматического подхвата классов, как в Java))

Comment: Загрузка была с помощью автолоада композера

Comment: Т.е. загрузка классов работает. Я в классе Test делал простой метод getString, который возвращал строку. Все работает, если не обращаться к классу Db, там он не может найти new PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полистав гугл, наткнулся на вот такой вызов класса PDO

Мой старый:

```
self::$_db = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '');
```

Мой новый:

```
self::$_db = new \PDO($dsn, 'root', '');
```

Дело в слеше.

Comment: Т.е. класс PDO встроен же в PHP (прослойка) и если вы используете в своем коде namespace, то нужно создавать именно через слеш new \PDO

Comment: Либо в начале файла написать `use \PDO`

Comment: Понял, принял. Спасибо.